# Filtering user input using regex in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a text area on my forum website and would like to filter text entered by user before saving on database. I'm using sanitize function to strip all html tags and then trying to use gsub with regex. The below is what I'm trying to use in my controller-

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(params[:content]).gsub(/[^0-9a-z\\s#]/im,'')
```

I'm able to strip html using sanitize but unable to get the correct regex for the gsub method. For my text area, I would like to allow the following for markdown editing-

- ###
- ####
- **
- *
- _
- -
- >>
- ~~
- ==
- .
- ://
- newline character for multiple lines
- spaces
- alphanumeric characters

I would like to replace all other characters with spaces for security.

I'm new to rails and regex so any pointers will be appreciated. Any other pointers for better secuirty would also be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: The great argument on why you are doing it wrong is: even being written and tested, your code would filter out punctuation (semicolons, colons, commas etc.) Just to filter out what the user had input is _not a security_, it’s a _user’s obscurity_. Why would you drop user’s math (∀ x ∈ R ⇒ ∃ ...)?

Comment: Please try `gsub(/(\#{3,4}|\*{1,2}|[\w. -]+|(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}|>{2}|:\/{2}|~{2}|={2})|./) { |m| m == $~[1] ? $~[1] : ' ' }`.

Comment: Thanks so much @stribizhev. I've edited it further to include few smileys, ! , - and it works now looks like - `gsub(/(\#{3,4}|\*{1,2}|[\w. -]+|[\w, +]+|[\w! +]+|[\w: +]+|["\w" +]+|[:-?) +]+|[(\w) +]+|(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}|>{2}|:\/{2}|~{2}|={2})|./) { |m| m == $~[1] ? $~[1] : ' ' }` . However can you explain what the last bit in curly braces is doing `{ |m| m == $~[1] ? $~[1] : ' ' }`

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for the comment. How do you think I should be securing my app from malicious user input without restricting what is allowed? I'm new to professional web development so any pointers would be appreciated...

Comment: @pari `sanitize` is supposed to secure you of injections already. Just provide users with an ability to enter whatever they wont, don’t screw them up.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks again..If I use sanitize alone. Will I Not be exposed to SQL injection or to the code that sanitize function cannot parse?

Comment: @pari: Shall I post my suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment since it worked for you.

My initial suggestion:

```
gsub(/(\#{3,4}|\*{1,2}|[\w. -]+|(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}|>{2}|:\/{2}|~{2}|={2})|./) { |m| m == $~[1] ? $~[1] : ' ' }
```

- `\#{3,4}` - Matches 3 or 4 `#`s
- `\*{1,2}` - Matches 1 or 2 `*`s
- `[\w. -]+` - Matches 1 or more alphanumeric characters or an underscore (`\w`), a dot `.` ord a hyphen `-`
- `(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}` - 2 or more line breaks (supporting all major OS newline flavors)
- `>{2}` - 2 `>`s
- `:\/{2}` - Literal `://`
- `~{2}` - 2 tildes
- `={2}` - 2 equal signs

The regex consists of a capturing group (marked with round brackets `(...)`) containing alternatives (joined with `|` symbol) of the substrings we need to keep (you listed them above), and the `.` matching the rest of characters that we'll be replacing.

The regex you say you have come up with is

```
(\#{3,4}|\*{1,2}|[\w. -]+|[\w, +]+|[\w! +]+|[\w: +]+|["\w" +]+|[:-?) +]+|[(\w) +]+|(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}|>{2}|:\/{2}|~{2}|={2})|.
```

It has some modified part `[\w, +]+|[\w! +]+|[\w: +]+|["\w" +]+|[:-?) +]+|[(\w) +]+`. You should be aware that `[...]` means *a character class*, any character inside it, *not a sequence of characters*. So, `["\w" +]` makes little sense since it does not mean `a quote, alphanumeric, a quote and some spaces`, it just means *either a quote, or an alphanumeric, or a space, or a plus symbol*.

Bigger concern is with `[:-?) +]`: the `-` here creates a range between `:` (58 dec number in [ASCII table](http://www.italysoft.com/utility/converters/ascii-table.php)) and `?` (63 dec symbol). Thus, it matches *a `:`, or a `;`, or a `<`, or a `=`, or a `>`, or a `?`, or a `)`, or a space, or a `+`.

I hope that information will help you adjusting the regex further.

As for `{ |m| m == $~[1] ? $~[1] : ' ' }`, it is a Ruby way to add a kind of a callback function: we run `gsub` and every time we have a match, we assign it to `m` variable, then we check if it is equal to the capturing group 1, then we replace the whole match with the contents of Group 1 (thus, we keep what we need), and if not, we replace with a space (as it was matched by the final `.` in our pattern).